# Code for extracting from the right side with cut command?

Tags: bash, substring, cut

There is a sample of using the `cut` command to extract parts of a string starting from the left. An example is given below.

```
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f-2
abc-def
```

How can the same code be adapted to extracting from the right side? I thought of reversing the words and applying the same method, but it was too complicated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you could use rev

```
echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | rev | cut -d- -f-2 | rev
```

Comment: This is what I use. Also for `uniq -F` since it doesn't support skipping from the end

Answer (score 7):

```
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f3-
ghi-jkl
```

`-2` cuts up to the 2nd field. `3-` cuts from the 3rd field on.

Comment: What would the -d parameter be if they are separated by spaces

Comment: -d\<space> followed by another space (so the space is a part of the parameter)

Comment: This only works if you know in advance how many fields each line will contain.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - 5 years after your answer and after revisiting it I think iruvar's answer is the better one. Given that he answered the question virtually at the same time as my comment I think it is only fair. Hopefully with over 193K ranking you shouldn't miss the points :). I had to revisit the problem today and remembered that I had a similar question on stackoverflow

Comment: Noooooooooooooo! :'-(